# Do we have spell checker?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There is at least one user on our site who constantly provides good/excellent answers. However, I can almost always find typos in his answers. Those typos do not impact the overall quality of the answers. Still, typos are typos.

I myself always want to have the spell checker available on our site. My workaround is to use my own word processor off-line to check the typos before I post an answer. This causes extra efforts.

My question is,

> Do we have spell checker available on stack exchange sites? If yes, how do I use it? If not, why?

Comment: Definitely second this request - sometimes we are tired and slip up.

Comment: While I may be that user, Firefox has a built in spell check.

Answer (score 7):

**Use your browser’s built-in spellchecker**. All three browsers I use (Firefox, Safari, Chrome) have it, and it does work for Stack Exchange's text boxes.

If you browser does not come with a spellchecker, [there are free plugins for that](http://www.howtogeek.com/76223/add-spell-checking-to-internet-explorer-9/).

Comment: I use IE. Believe or not, there are still many IE users.

Comment: @scaaahu I believe you, but I find it hard to believe that IE does not have a built-in spellchecker. Searching the web reveals that there are [plenty of such free plugins](http://www.howtogeek.com/76223/add-spell-checking-to-internet-explorer-9/), however

Comment: The computer I am using is Vista. I am using IE9. My problem is, the machine is my wife's. She can have it anytime she wants. I am retiree. No budget to get a new computer. My own one is XP. I cannot even install IE9.

Comment: @scaaahu [another free spellchecker](http://www.speckie.com/dload), compatible with Windows XP and IE ≥ 6

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try.